# How to use wildcard in a for loop using batch cmd

Tags: android, batch-file

> My question is how can i use the wildcard in the "virusDB"?
>
> here is my batch code

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /F "tokens=*" %%A in (packages) do (
set packages=%%A
for /F "tokens=*" %%A in (virusDB) do (
set virusDB=%%A
if !packages! == !virusDB! echo !packages!>>virus.txt
)
)
exit
```

> inside my "packages" are
>
> 825165.apk
>   965464.apk com.android.apps.start2-1.apk com.dianxinos.dxbs-1.apk com.dianxinos.optimizer.duplay-1.apk
>
> inside my "virusDB" are
>
> 1*.apk 2*.apk 3*.apk 4*.apk 5*.apk 6*.apk 7*.apk 8*.apk 9*.apk
>   com.android.apps.xxxx.apk com.dianxinos.xxxx.apk
>   com.dianxinos.optimizer.xxxx.apk and etc...
>
> output using the batch code are
>
> com.android.apps.xxxx.apk com.dianxinos.xxxx.apk
>   com.dianxinos.optimizer.xxxx.apk
>
> my expected output are`enter code here`
>
> 825165.apk
>   965464.apk com.android.apps.xxxx.apk com.dianxinos.xxxx.apk com.dianxinos.optimizer.xxxx.apk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`==` comparison in `if !packages! == !virusDB!` specifies a true condition if the specified text strings match *exactly* (i.e. no character is considered to be a wildcard).

Desired output *could* come from next [`findstr` command](http://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html) having in mind limited and non-standard `findstr` support for regular expressions: `echo !packages!| findstr /I "!virusDB!"`.

Supposing that `*` in strings inside `virusDB` file should mean *any characters*  wildcard **and** there is at most one `*` in any particular string, next script shows possible way of modifying that strings to become a valid `findstr` *regex* (uncomment `echo "%virusDB%" =^> "%FindstrRegEx%"` command to see resultant *regex*). Explanation in `rem` comments:

```
@ECHO OFF >NUL
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
rem change the current directory/folder and store the previous folder/path
pushd "%~dp0"

    rem  ↓↓↓ debugging output ↓↓↓
echo(
echo === virusDB ===
type virusDB
echo(
echo === packages ===
type packages
echo(
echo === result (not redirected to "virus.txt" yet^) ===
    rem ↑↑↑ debugging output ↑↑↑  

for /F "tokens=*" %%A in (virusDB) do (
  set "virusDB=%%A"
  call :packages
)

rem change directory back to the path/folder most recently stored by the PUSHD command
popd
ENDLOCAL
goto :eof

:packages
      rem escape Findstr regex wildcard dot to literal dot
  set "FindstrRegEx=%virusDB:.=\.%"
      rem change cmd wildcard * to Findstr regex wildcard .*
      rem get suffix
  set "FindstrRTail=%FindstrRegEx:**=%"
  if "%FindstrRegEx%" == "%FindstrRTail%" goto :noAsterisk
      rem get prefix
  call set "FindstrRPrfx=%%FindstrRegEx:%FindstrRTail%=%%"
      rem build regex
  set "FindstrRegEx=%FindstrRPrfx:~,-1%.*%FindstrRTail%
  :noAsterisk
      rem ToDo: change cmd wildcard ? to appropriate Findstr regex wildcard

      rem add Findstr regex line position anchor ^   (??? and $ as well ???)
  set "FindstrRegEx=^%FindstrRegEx%$"
  rem debug output echo "%virusDB%" =^> "%FindstrRegEx%"
      rem look for `regex` in "packages" file
  for /F "delims=" %%G in ('findstr /I "%FindstrRegEx%" packages') do (
      echo %virusDB% =match= %%G
  )
goto :eof
```

Unfortunately, above approach will fail (i.e. could give false positives) if a name in `virusDB` file would contain a space. Switch to PowerShell in the case.

**Output**:

> ```
> ==> D:\bat\SO\40654032\40654032.bat
>
> === virusDB ===
> 1*.apk
> 8*.apk
> 9*.apk
> com.android.apps.*.apk
> com.dianxinos.xxxx.apk
> com.dianxinos.optimizer.xxxx.apk
>
> === packages ===
> 825165.apk
> 965464.apk
> com.android.apps.start2-1.apk
> com.dianxinos.dxbs-1.apk
> 9com.dianxinos.optimizer.duplay-1.apk
>
> === result (not redirected to "virus.txt" yet) ===
> 8*.apk =match= 825165.apk
> 9*.apk =match= 965464.apk
> 9*.apk =match= 9com.dianxinos.optimizer.duplay-1.apk
> com.android.apps.*.apk =match= com.android.apps.start2-1.apk
>
> ==>
> ```

**Resources** (required reading, incomplete):

- (command reference) [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/)
- (additional particularities) [Windows CMD Shell Command Line Syntax](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax.html)
- (`%~A` etc. special page) [Command Line arguments (Parameters)](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html)
- (`%FindstrRPrfx:~,-1%`) [Extract part of a variable (substring)](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-substring.html)
- (`%virusDB:.=\.%` etc.) [Variable Edit/Replace](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-replace.html)

Comment: I think your right sir i need to switch to PowerShell. I can use the wildcard but i think i need to manualy type all the names inside virusDB in my batch script which is not practical or create a batch to create another batch including all the names inside the virusDB.(correct me if im wrong) but anyway i would like to thank all your effort sir for helping me.

Comment: My pleasure. Please consider [accepting the answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5235) if you find that it solved your problem. Please ask another question for PowerShell solution (and I'd pay attention to sample data formatting ☺).